# How to change the text of a label when clicked without using buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a table with collapsible cells that I'd like to change the text of when expanded. Specifically, when the cells are collapsed, a plus sign exists next to the cell text (so as to signal to the user that there is more to see), and the text "(Click to expand...)" is shown. I would like, however, to replace the plus sign with a minus sign when the label is clicked, and to erase the "(Click to expand...)" text.

The issue I am facing is that the minus sign icon and plus sign icon appear together and disappear together, rather than the minus sign replacing the plus sign and vice versa. How would I go about making them replace each other with every collapse/expand?

Below is a working example of a simplified version of my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();
  $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function() {
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "'] i.fa-plus-circle").toggle();
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "'] i.fa-minus-circle").toggle();
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "'] span").toggle();
    $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
[data-toggle="toggle"] {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  display: block;
}

.fa-minus-circle {
  display: none;
}

table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<table>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="label" for="person">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
            <b>Person</b>
            <span class="clicktoexpand">(Click to expand...)</span>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="person" data-toggle="toggle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class="people">Jack</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="jack">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="people">Jill</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="jill">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="label" for="place">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
          <b>Place</b> 
          <span class="clicktoexpand">(Click to expand...)</span>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="place" data-toggle="toggle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class="city">LA</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="nyc">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="city">NYC</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="nyc">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why don't you change those things within the change function of the data-toggle? Basically just add the code after `$(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();` in your JS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is one of the first things I did, but I think I might be using the `.innerHTML` DOM property wrong because the errors exist in the HTML replacement part of the function. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/h5wmd806/

Comment: jQuery uses the [`.html()` function](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to set inner HTML code. `.innerHTML()` is a part of vanilla JS, it can not be used with jQuery.

Comment: Hah, I actually wrote that initially but had doubts and changed it. Still, even with `.html()` it's not working (I updated the jsfiddle to show this).

Comment: The jsfiddle was not updated, but I also noticed, that you use `$('fa fa-plus-circle')` as the selector, which misses the dots, which are needed to select classes. So, you want to change your selector to `$('.fa.fa-plus-circle')` to select all elements, which have both the classes fa and fa-plus-circle.

Comment: My apologies, thank you for pointing that out. Working fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/bq1vxz39/. The issue I am facing now is that the minus sign doesn't replace the plus sign and also doesn't disappear once the cell collapses. As well, the (Click to expand...) doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the "(Click to expand...)" inside of a `<span>` as well as adding "`<i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>`" and hiding it with js. Then just toggle everything along with "`<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>`"

**The finished code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();
  $('.fa-minus-circle').hide(); //This hides the minus button
  $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function() {
  
    //This takes the label of the same id as the input, so we can get their children. Afterwards we toggle everything.
    $("label[for='"+this.id+"'] i.fa-plus-circle").toggle()
    $("label[for='"+this.id+"'] i.fa-minus-circle").toggle()
    $("label[for='"+this.id+"'] span").toggle()

    $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();    
    
  });
});
```

```css
[data-toggle="toggle"]{
  display: none;
}

.label {
  display: block;
}

table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="label" for="person">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                
                <!-- New minus <i> -->
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                
                <!-- Click to expand inside span <i> -->
                <b>Person</b> <span>(Click to expand...)</span>
              </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="person" data-toggle="toggle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class="people">Jack</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="jack">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="people">Jill</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="jill">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="label" for="place">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                
                <!-- New minus <i> -->
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                
                <!-- Click to expand inside span <i> -->
                <b>Place</b> <span>(Click to expand...)</span>
              </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="place" data-toggle="toggle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class="city">LA</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="la">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="city">NYC</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="nyc">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is cool, thank you for the response. One small issue: the plus sign and minus sign appear and disappear together rather than replacing each other. See: https://jsfiddle.net/wy5vnj6h/ Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @ttoshiro Oh yes, it seems that hiding the minus circle with CSS doesn't work. Instead, hide it with js using `$('.fa-minus-circle').hide()` just after `$('.hide').hide();`. I'll change the answer now.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This does almost what you asked for:

```
if($(this).parents().next('.hide').is(':visible'))
    $(this).prev("label").text("-")
else
    $(this).prev("label").text("(Click to expand...)")
```

It selects the label sibling that holds the text that you want to modify and checks if the element that you hid is visible or not, then changes the text inside. because "Person" and "Place" are a part of the labels' text they're being overwritten. this can be solved by multiple ways, ones of which is nesting the text to be changed in another html tag and instead of changing the labels' text changing that tag's text content
aka wrapping it with a `<span></span>`. see:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();
  $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function() {
    $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
    if($(this).parents().next('.hide').is(':visible'))
        $(this).prev("label").find("span").text("-")
    else
        $(this).prev("label").find("span").text("(Click to expand...)")
  });
});
```

```css
[data-toggle="toggle"] {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  display: block;
}

table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="label" for="person">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                <b>Person</b> <span>(Click to expand...)</span>
              </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="person" data-toggle="toggle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class="people">Jack</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="jack">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="people">Jill</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="jill">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="label" for="place">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                <b>Place</b> <span>(Click to expand...)</span>
              </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="place" data-toggle="toggle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class="city">LA</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="nyc">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="city">NYC</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="nyc">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used parts of this answer to fit the situation but faced some issues (edited into the original post). When trying to do it with the plus/minus sign, the plus sign doesn't get replaced, and the minus sign doesn't disappear after the cell gets collapsed. Any ideas?

Comment: I saw your comment under @ezeKG answer with the jsfiddle but I can't reply to it because I am lacking in points.
Basically you need to set the - sign to hidden then when you toggle both of your + and - they'll show and hide as you desire, just add $("i.fa-minus-circle").hide(); to your documentReady listener

Answer (score 1):

I added a span with class arround your text.

I used the function parent() to get to td previous tag and find() function to the span tag and a "close" class name to your button to check if it's close or not in a condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();
  $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').click(function() {
    if($(this).is('.close')) {
       $(this).parent('td').find('b:first').text('Person (-)');
       $(this).parent('td').find('.textLabel').text('');
       $(this).removeClass('close');
    } else {
       $(this).parent('td').find('b:first').text("Person");   
       $(this).parent('td').find('.textLabel').text('(Click to expand...)');
       $(this).addClass('close');
    }
    $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
[data-toggle="toggle"] {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  display: block;
}

table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="label" for="person">
           <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
           <b>Person</b> <span class="textLabel">(Click to expand...)</span>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="person" data-toggle="toggle" class="close">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class="people">Jack</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="jack">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="people">Jill</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="jill">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="section">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label class="label" for="place">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                <b>Place</b> <span class="textLabel">(Click to expand...)</span>
              </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="place" data-toggle="toggle" class="close">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class="city">LA</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="nyc">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="city">NYC</td>
      <td class="right cell" id="nyc">
        <span>0</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```